# how to display today's most viewed posts order by custom meta "views"

Tags: posts

I wanna display **today's most viewed post list** ?
order by custom meta = views

Is it possible ?

Comment: WordPress does not natively capture any stats. Are you using any plugins or services to capture such information?

Comment: im using my functions it updates the views cutom meta smilar to postwievs

Answer (score 1):

If you have value stored in simple enough format you can use `meta_key` and `meta_value_num` query arguments to sort by it. See [Order & Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) in Codex.

Comment: i did but didint work.
the query 

**code** here;

$today->query('post_type=portfolyo&showposts=15&meta_key=views&orderby=meta_value&order=desc');

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$today->query('post_type=portfolyo&showposts=15&meta_key=views&orderby=meta_value_num&order‌​=desc');
```

changes is "`orderby=meta_value_num`"

Comment: @FatihToprak Why not accept the answer then?

Comment: What you mean Fegter ?